# d3 geo.path Transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a maps of different countries. I want to transition every countries to another path (typically a rectangle or a circle).

If I do a classic transition, the transition is akward, as the SVG does not have the same number of nodes. I use a library (polymorph.js). This library ensures that the destination path has the same number of nodes. Sadly there are some artfacts ( circles are not really circle, and rectangles are a bit weird).

Example : http://bl.ocks.org/ufenegga/7302cdde0fd2b6814dda

I am looking for an algorithm that allows to transition nicely between the country path and a circle/rect

Can anybody help ?

Thanks

Comment: I have found this : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153. So i replicated the approach for a rectangle here : http://bl.ocks.org/ufenegga/b62c7332ce35abfdfe8b. But there is one last problem. How to find the good starting point when i interpolate between the two paths : that is how to be the sure that the upper left 'part' of the first path stay the upper left part of the second path. It is only by trial-and-error that my example works

Answer (score 0):

I find a working solution here : https://gist.github.com/ge045/2e7de433f1d1d5948bbd/revisions

If somebody can explains what is going on, so i'll be sure to understand how it works